# StaticLayout render wrongly with Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, staticlayout

I render text via `StaticLayout` and draw it in `onDraw()` in my custom view, not `TextView`. Everything works fine until I test my application with `Android Nougat`. In some cases, `StaticLayout` is created wrongly with `lineWidth` bigger than the `outerWidth` that I passed in `constructor()`. So It causes my custom view renders wrongly. (outside the limited area)
`Android Marshmallow`, expected result.
[image]

`Andorid Nougat`, unexpected result.
[image]

```
StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, outerwidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
for (int i = 0; i < textLayout.getLineCount(); i++) {
    lineWidth = textLayout.getLineWidth(i); // lineWidth sometimes is bigger than outerWidth
    ....
}
```

I don't know what the rule is to cause that error. (If I change the outerWidth or the text, the error doesn't happen.)
Could anyone help em? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who knows this issue?

Comment: It seems android 7.1 doesn't fix that bug. But it doesn't happen when I use TextView. Anyone can helps?

Comment: Everyone knows this issues?